# Create a file with content through ssh without a text editor

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am aware that it is possible to create a file in ssh through the "touch" command then editing it using text editors such as vi or pico to edit them and add content.

I was wondering if it was possible to create a file and add it's contents in one command line?
Something like:

`[create file command] [filename.txt] ["this is the contents of filename.txt"]`

The reason I'm asking if this was possible is because I have an [ssh client in Go](https://gist.github.com/linuz-ly/4148437) where a session only accepts one call to run and I plan to use this for an app that is automated with no user inputs so I want to avoid using text editors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
ssh [user@]hostname 'echo "this is the contents of filename.txt" > <path/filename>'
```

The echo with ">" overwrites an existing file, or creates a new file if it doesn't exist.

Replace ">" with ">>" to append the text to an existing file.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I guess the "ssh [user@]hostname" was to connect to remote, but the ssh client in Go already connest so I just needed to run the "'echo "this is the contents of filename.txt" >/tmp/filename.txt'" and I was all set, thanks!!